# Prove that $f(x) = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d$ is monotonous

Tags: calculus, polynomials

> Let $f(x) = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d$ Be a polynomial.
>
> 1. If $b^2 \le 3ac $, prove that $f$ is monotonic
> 2. Prove that the graph of $f$ consists of two parts: the first one is concave upwards, and the second portion is concave downwards. Show that the inflection point is $f(\frac{-b}{3a}).$

For the first part I tried watching what happens with the coefficients of the polynomial given that $b^2 \le 3ac $. We have that $0 \le 3ac $. Meaning there are two cases:

$i) a \gt 0 $ and $c \gt 0$ or

$ ii) a \lt 0$ and $c \lt 0$.

I could also pick possibilities for the coefficients in general. Like, what happens if $a \lt b \lt c \lt d$, but there are two many cases, like 24. If $a,c$ share the same sign though, that would reduce the possibilities. But in general, i think that I am lacking some crucial theory here, and I don't know what is the approach for solving this problem.

For the second part i realized that that if i first divide $f$ by $a$, then I can transform $f$ into another polynomial $g(x) =  f(x - \frac{b}{3a})$, and so I wonder If this can help me to show that $f(\frac{-b}{3a})$ is an inflection point.

Comment: Probably going to need to look at the first and second derivatives.

Comment: do you mean monotonic? Polynomials are boring and all, but that's a bit rude

Comment: I assume (please correct me) that the requirement is to prove monotonicity, and if that is the case then given that f is a polynomial and therefore continuous and differentiate everywhere can't you just differentiate and establish the conditions where f' is always increasing or always decreasing?

Comment: Yeah well I differentiated, I get $f' = 3ax^2 + 2 bx + c$ if i get the roots of this i can then evaluate these points on $f''$ and get the maximum minumum and inflection points. I don't see what does this have to do with monotonicity...

Comment: In some interval if f'" is greater than 0' f is increasing, and is monotonous? In the other case is decreasing, so it is monotonous? That's it?

Comment: I find continually pointing out the correct word her is *monotonic* quite *monotonous*!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f'(x)=3ax^2+2bx+c$

Discriminent($D$)=$4(b^2-3ac)$

Now if $a>0$ and $b^2\leq 3ac$, $f'(x)\geq 0$, hence $f(x)$ is increasing.

If $a<0$ and $b^2\leq 3ac$, $f'(x)\leq 0$, hence $f(x)$ is decreasing.

Hence first part is proved.

For the $2$nd part do double derivative, we know if $f''(x)>0$ then $f(x)$ is convex at those points and concave for the opposite.

Answer (score 1):

From where you left off: $\triangle' = b^2 - 3ac \le 0$ by assumption, so the sign of $f$ is the same of $a$. So $f$ is monotonically increasing if $a > 0$, and decreasing if $a < 0$.

The other part is $f''(x) = 6ax + 2b = 0 \implies x = -\dfrac{b}{3a}$, and this is the inflection point, showing the two parts.